# Not able to print out the Array Elements

Tags: java, arrays, file

This code is to get the firstName, LastName, and StudentID by reading it from a file and displaying the information in the main file. When I run my program, instead of printing the information of the students, it prints out a chain of characters and numbers.

```java
public class main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
        Student[] students = new Student[10];
        getStudentData(students);

        for (int i = 0; i < students.length; i++){
            System.out.println(students[i]);
        }
    }


    public static void getStudentData(Student[] students){
        String infileName = "studentlist.txt";
        Scanner reader = null;
        try {
            reader = new Scanner (new File(infileName));
            int index = 0;
            while(reader.hasNext()){
                String oneLine = reader.nextLine();
                String[] parts = oneLine.split(" ");
                long studentID = Long.parseLong(parts[2]);
                students[index] = new Student(parts[0],parts[1],studentID);
                index++;
            }
        } catch (FileNotFoundException err) {
            System.out.println(err);
        } finally {
            if (reader != null)
                reader.close();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Please provide the content of your `studentlist.txt` file (or at least a few lines).

Comment: Have you defined a `toString()` method on your `Student` class? You need to do this otherwise the default `toString()` implementation of class `Object` will be used.

Comment: Thank you so much, yeap I make a mistake for not defining a toString() method in my Student Class.

Answer (score 0):

Have you defined a `toString()` method on your `Student` class?
You need to do this otherwise the default `toString()` implementation of the superclass for all classes (class `Object`) will be used which returns the `name of the class` concatenated with `@` and the hashcode of the class in hexadecimal format.

Add this method to your `Student` class and return a meaningful `String` containing the attribute values of a `Student` object instead of my descriptive `String`.

```java
@Override
public String toString() {
    return "return a string here that represents the student and his/ her attribute values";
}
```

FYI: Many IDEs can generate an arbitrary `toString()` method for you.

See the [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29140402/how-do-i-print-my-java-object-without-getting-sometype2f92e0f4#:%7E:text=The%20Object.toString()%20method,of%20the%20object%20in%20hexadecimal.) for more details on `Object::toString()`.